# Get row height of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im doing c# asp.net in web form, I would like to get the row height of grid view but cant, I always show 0 when I tried to get it. I using the code from other post inside Stack Overflow.

c#

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
{
   height = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Height.Value) + height;
}
```

html

```
<wc:ReportGridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPrintPaging="true"
 CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True"
tyle="font-family: 'Century Gothic'; font-size: small; z-index: -1; color: #000000;
 margin-top: 0px;" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px">
```

I see all comment said they can work but why I can't? or got other solution to get the row height no matter is c# or JavaScript.

Comment: Can you show us how the GridView is defined?

Comment: @devlin carnate Sorry, what is your mean by "how the gridview is defined“？

Comment: Show us your code from the aspx page where you have `<asp:GridView...`

Comment: @devlincarnate done edit, thank you

Comment: And I using a button to run "foreach" function above.

Comment: I'm not near my dev computer.  I'll take a look tomorrow and let you know, or maybe you will have another response by then.

Comment: Can you debug it and make sure the `foreach` statement is called?

Comment: @Heinz Siahaan yes Im sure, I had also put into an arraylist and all show 0.

Answer (score 0):

Row heightsin gridview can vary in size, so you can get height of specific row.

```
int x = grdvw1.Rows[0].Height;
```

It's also available from the row  template:

```
int x = grdvw1.RowTemplate.Height
```

**Updated**-For WebForms,I dont think you can get this height by server side programming as it depends on how browser render.You can try it by using client side programming.Still you can wait for experts comment.In case client side satisfy your need,you can try below code.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            debugger;
            var a = $("#gvd").height();
            alert(a);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Gridview should be under **gvd** div .

```
<div id="gvd">

        <asp:gridview runat="server" ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPrintPaging="true"
 CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"  ShowFooter="True" rowstyle Height="20px"
tyle="font-family: 'Century Gothic'; font-size: small; z-index: -1; color: #000000;
 margin-top: 0px;" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" 
            DataKeyNames="CorporateEmployeeId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
               //Bounded columns
            </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
        </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [mytable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
```

Comment: This not work for me, i think your answer is for win form, for mine is .Height.Value, but also get 0.

Comment: you wont get any row height as it depends on how browser renders it.Only possiblity is via client side.I dont think ,server side programming will give row height of gridview in web forms.See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the row height for each row using JQuery / JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//iterate over each row that has cells and log the height
     $("#<%=gv.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").each(function () {
         console.log($(this).height());
     });
});
```

I don't believe you can get the row height from code-behind because the table has not yet rendered on the client, so there is no row height.

Comment: I was thinking what if I try to measure a gridview that alread rendered by a button clicked?

Comment: If you mean you want to do a postback on button click and get the height from code behind, you can't.  The GridView is no longer rendered when the page posts.  You could get the height using the code above and put the result in a hidden field in a column of your GridView, and retrieve the value from that hidden field in each row in code behind.

Comment: ya, currently Im doing this way by using the javascript. But I try looking for someone answer who can do it in codebehind. Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly sure my idea will work.  Get the height on client side using JavaScript, and save to a hidden input on each row in the GridView.  It will then be available in code behind.

Comment: ya right. Dear @devlin carnate . Im currently code like what you said and it works. But Im looking for another ways which can using code behind to control it. Thank you.

Comment: Or save the value of the height as a data attribute on the tr of each row.  You can also access that from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<RowStyle>` element to your `GridView` defintion.

For example:

```
<wc:ReportGridView ID="gv" runat="server" ...>
  <RowStyle Height="40px" />
</wc:ReportGridView>
```

According to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.height(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default is `Empty`, which indicates that this property is not set.

Comment: Hi @dariom , I would like to get the height because of the vary of record length cause my gridview extend until second page, that is no point I set it before I rendered it. Thank you.